# how to configure a service client object in the JavaScript SDK v3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-js

From example [here](https://gist.github.com/andrhamm/b0f847fc2e344f9cfb2e12f81e11dae1) i want to know how we can achieve in aws sdk JS v3?

The following example configures a service client object in javascript sdk object in v2. I want to know how we can achieve something like this in aws-sdk js v3?

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const { Service, apiLoader } = AWS;

apiLoader.services.personalize = {};
AWS.Personalize = Service.defineService('personalize', ['2018-05-22']);
Object.defineProperty(apiLoader.services.personalize, '2018-05-22', {
  get: function get() {
    const model = require('./aws-api-model-personalize.json');
    model.paginators = {};
    return model;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
});

apiLoader.services['personalize-runtime'] = {};
AWS.PersonalizeRuntime = Service.defineService('personalize-runtime', ['2018-05-22']);
Object.defineProperty(apiLoader.services['personalize-runtime'], '2018-05-22', {
  get: function get() {
    const model = require('./aws-api-model-personalize-runtime.json');
    model.paginators = {};
    return model;
  },
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true,
});

// initialize an instance of the Personalize service client
const personalize = new AWS.Personalize({ apiVersion: '2018-05-22' });

// use it
personalize.listDatasetGroups().promise().then((resp) => {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda figured out, In v3 seems like the clients can't be loaded in runtime. WE have to generate our own Typescript client. Using [smithy](https://smithy.io/2.0/index.html) Just like they do all clients in aws-sdk v3 and use them.